# XAML binding nested struct from ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: binding, struct, nested, observablecollection, windows-phone

I am building a Windows Phone App, and I am trying to bind the ObservableCollection with nested struct without success.

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    private Player _Player1;
    public Player Player1
    {
        get { return _Player1; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_Player1))
            {
                _Player1 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Player1);
            }
        }
    }
    private Player _Player2;
    public Player Player2
    {
        get { return _Player2; }
        set
        {
            if (!value.Equals(_Player2))
            {
                _Player2 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Player2);
            }
        }
    }
    public struct Player
    {
        public string Name;
        public bool IsWinner;
    }
}
```

MyPageViewModel.cs

```
public class MyPageViewModel : Screen
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyViewModel> Matches { get; private set; }
    public MyPageViewModel()
    {
        this.Matches = new ObservableCollection<MyViewModel>();
        LoadData();
    }
    public void LoadData()
    {            
        // Matches
        this.Matches.Add(new MyViewModel()
        { 
            Player1 = new MyViewModel.Player
            { Name = "Jhonn", IsWinner = false },
            Player2 = new MyViewModel.Player
            { Name = "Marrie", IsWinner = true }
        });
    }
}
```

MyPage.xaml

```
<ListBox Margin="0,0,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Matches}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player1.Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Player2.Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I have no binding error, but no players names are showed. I always have a blank screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
public struct Player
{
    public string Name;
    public bool IsWinner;
}
```

In order to be bound, Name needs to be a property.  Make Player a class and expose Name as a property on the class and you'll be golden:

```
public class Player
{
     public string Name {get; set;}
     public bool IsWinner {get;set;}
}
```

You should be able to get away without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, as long as you only set them one time.  If they're going to change, go ahead and implement INPC.